# Configuring the tasks package

Tags: tasks

The tasks package forms a list like this

```
* a * b
* c * d
* e * f
```

How to configure the package to display such a list

```
* a * d
* b * e
* c * f
```

?

Also need to have line alignment as `tasks` does, `multicols` does not do this

[image]

Comment: No, you also need to have line alignment as well as tasks does, multicols does not do this.

Comment: If you want that readers go down first and then move to the next column, alignment has no meaning. You want to vertically align only if the tasks have to be read in the normal reading sense (first left-to-right and then top-to-bottom).

Comment: In theory, you can get used to the format of the tasks package list. The main thing is to have a neat alignment.

Answer (score 4):

A quick and dirty solution.

With a little manual intervention: save (before the list) your highest item here:
`\sbox{\myhighitem}{<write here your highest item>}`.

*Explanation*

```
\newlist{mylist}{enumerate}{10}
```

creates the new list environment `mylist`, like `enumerate`, with at max 10 levels of depth.

```
\setlist[mylist]{label =\alph*),
  before = \raggedcolumns\begin{multicols}{2},
  after = \end{multicols}}
```

sets the alphabetical label and the list in two columns with `multicols`.

```
\newsavebox{\myhighitem}
```

creates the box `\myhighitem`, to know what boxes are, see here: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Boxes.

```
\newcommand{\myitem}{\item\vphantom{\usebox{\myhighitem}}}
```

creates a new command for `\item` that also sets the vertical dimension of the item as the height of `\myhighitem`. Using `\vphantom` you set a vertical dimension without writing anything.

```
\sbox{\myhighitem}{$\dfrac{e+f}{g-h}$}
```

saves in `\myhighitem` the string `$\dfrac{e+f}{g-h}$`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{multicol}
\newlist{mylist}{enumerate}{10}
\setlist[mylist]{label =\alph*),
    before = \raggedcolumns\begin{multicols}{2},
    after = \end{multicols}}

\newsavebox{\myhighitem}
\newcommand{\myitem}{\item\vphantom{\usebox{\myhighitem}}}

\begin{document}
You can use a trick:
\sbox{\myhighitem}{$\dfrac{e+f}{g-h}$}% write here your highest item
\begin{mylist}
\myitem $\dfrac{a+b}{b}$
\myitem $c+d$
\myitem $\dfrac{e+f}{g-h}$
\myitem $m-n$
\myitem $o-p$
\myitem $\dfrac{i+j}{k-l}$
\end{mylist}

You can do it also at ``row level'':
\begin{mylist}
\sbox{\myhighitem}{$\dfrac{a+b}{c}$}% write here your highest item of the first row
\myitem $\dfrac{a+b}{b}$
\sbox{\myhighitem}{$cp$}% write here your highest item of the third row
\myitem $c+d$
\sbox{\myhighitem}{$\dfrac{e+f}{g-h}$}% write here your highest item of the third row
\myitem $\dfrac{e+f}{g-h}$
\sbox{\myhighitem}{$\dfrac{a+b}{c}$}% write here your highest item of the first row
\myitem $m-n$
\sbox{\myhighitem}{$cp$}% write here your highest item of the third row
\myitem $o-p$
\sbox{\myhighitem}{$\dfrac{e+f}{g-h}$}% write here your highest item of the third row
\myitem $\dfrac{i+j}{k-l}$
\end{mylist}
\end{document}
```

[image]